# PHP and MySQL Sort Date

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got a question about sorting the MySQL output in a column where my date ist stored.
The format is "10.01.2014 - 16:01 - Fr.".

I've got a query is as followed:

```
SELECT * FROM `jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung` ORDER BY `res_date` ASC
```

The problem is, that it only orders the date with the first number. So for example "10.01.2014 - xxxx" is before "12.12.2013 - xxxx".

Any idea how i can solve this?

Comment: Yes, don't store your dates as strings.

Comment: Use real time datatypes for storing dates.

Comment: Use the mysql datetime field YYYY-MM-DD or you are in for lots of problems.

Comment: John's point is that there are specific data types for dates so that you can sort them properly; you can then use formatting commands in either mysql or php to display the date in the form you want. If your source data is storing the date as a string, you should use an ETL script to convert it to a datetime.

Comment: Store dates in the mysql date format. If you can't anymore, you still can think about sorting them through PHP using `asort` after querying them, even though it is NOT a really valuable solution.

Comment: The problem is, that the date is given from a joomla chronoforms datetime picker as a string. Is there no way to sort the string? I need the format exactly this way "10.01.2014 - 16:01 - Fr."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert from string to a true date representation.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Something like this could you work (but you may need to play with the format):

```
SELECT * 
FROM jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(res_date, '%M.%d.%Y %h:%i') ASC
```

The format string above is only a suggestion - be sure to check that you have a correct conversion from the string to the actual date it should represent.

Comment: This solution works for the date, but not the time. I've tried STR_TO_DATE(`res_date`, '%d.%m.%Y - %h:%i'), but it does not work. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Played with the format specifiers, and got the following to work: `select str_to_date('10.01.2014 - 16:01 - Fr', '%m.%d.%Y - %H:%i' );`. For the specifiers, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung` ORDER BY DATE(`res_date`) ASC

|| 

SELECT * FROM `jtmpl2_chronoforms_data_test_reservierung` ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`res_date`,'%Y%m%d') ASC
```